# How to access Session value from Angularjs.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, session

i wants to access session value from angular js.or set it in a text field.But its not working.

```
<input type="text" id="uname" value="<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>" ng-model="username" readonly="readonly">
```

when i  set the value of normal text field its working, like

```
<input type="text" id="uname" value="<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>"  readonly="readonly">
```

but after adding `ng-model` its not working.
How i will do this?Please anybody help me.

Comment: It will be good if you move the `session.getAttribute("username")` to controlelr

Comment: How will do this?@Sravan

Comment: Use JSP on JavaScript files is clearly a bad solution. And controller is placed in JS. So if you want to use this approach, you need come client-server communication get session values from server.

Answer (score 5):

It's angular's normal behavior. Try to use
  `ng-value="'<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>'"` which is better
or
`ng-init="username = '<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>'"`

Comment: <input type="text" id="username" ng-init="username = <%=session.getAttribute("username")%>"   readonly="readonly">     But when i call it $scope.username, it return undifined @Anton Stepanenkov

Comment: @Sdg Sorry, forgot to add quotation around '<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>'. I've edited the answer

Comment: What would be the syntax for setAttribute when wanting to set an angular variable to the session parameter?